# Two .AndroidStudio folders in Users\[username] directory

Tags: android, android-studio

Hello I have two folders in my user directory:

.AndroidStudio1.2  ~700mb
.AndroidStudio1.3  ~470mb

I've recently updated Android Studio to latest (1.3) version. Can I delete the first folder?

Comment: It is 2018 and I have 1.3, 1.5, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 3.0, 3.1, with a total space of 5.3GB, This is...unnecessary, I guess.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can delete the 1.2 version. 
It is not needed since you upgraded to 1.3.
Also folders are created when you switch update channels (stable,beta,canary,...)